# How to write `cat` in Go using pipes

Tags: unix, go

I have an implementation of the Unix tool `cat` below. It reads a number of bytes from `os.Stdin` into a buffer, then writes those bytes out to `os.Stdout`.  Is there a way I can skip the buffer and just pipe `Stdin` directly to `Stdout`?

```
package main

import "os"
import "io"

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)

    var n int
    var err error
    for err != io.EOF {
        n, err = os.Stdin.Read(buf)

        if n > 0 {
            os.Stdout.Write(buf[0:n])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about Go, but cat also reads files from the command line as well as stdin...so if you're re-implementing, you'll need to include that feature as well.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass Thanks, but I'm not actually creating a drop-in replacement for `cat`, just playing with Stdin/Stdout as an exercise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `io.Copy()` [(Documentation here)](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy)

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "io"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse, io.Copy uses a loop and a buffer much like the original code.

Comment: @nos I guess one could use `syscall.Sendfile()`, but I think that wasn't the OP's point.

Comment: @nos @Staven actually I would prefer to avoid copying into a buffer at all. How would I do that with `Sendfile()`?

Comment: @Sam `Sendfile()` is pretty much the Linux `sendfile()` system call behind a thin Go wrapper; see `man sendfile` for documentation. Unless you've confirmed that `Copy()` is a bottleneck, you shouldn't bother with it.

Answer (score 5):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
}
```